# How can akka persistent actor be started with guaranteed particular message received first?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, persistent

My actor extends akka.persistence.PersistentActor.
I want to send a message case class SetConfig(config: String) at first and make sure no other message is processed before SetConfig is persisted and applied.

What is the best practice to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Akka [FSM](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html) together with `PersistentActor`.

You can have these 2 states:

```
sealed trait State
case object Idle extends State
case object Active extends State
```

and this data:

```
sealed trait Data
case object Uninitialized extends Data
final case class Config(config: String) extends Data
```

you actor will extend `FSM[State, Data]`, and will:

```
startWith(Idle, Uninitialized)
```

Then you can say that you only accept `SetConfig` messages when `Idle`:

```
when(Idle) {
  case Event(SetConfig(conf), Uninitialized) =>
    goto(Active) using Config(conf)
}
```

and once you transition to `Active` you can receive other messages with:

```
when(Active) {
  case Event(...

// don't forget to start it up in initial state with:
initialize()
```

Finally on state transitions you can persist your state using regular Akka Persistence patterns.